# Given the following life expectancy data, what is the probability of living to age 70?

Tags: probability

The problem: Let $P(n)$ be the probability of reaching the age of $n$ years. Suppose that we are given $P(50) = .913; P(55) = .881; P(65) = .746$. If the probability that a man who just turned $65$ will die within $5$ years is $.16$, what is the probability for a man to survive until his $70^{th}$ birthday, i.e., what is $P(70)$?

I think I know what the answer is, but my solution may as well be magic - I have little idea how or why my answer is correct. I know it has something to do with conditional probability but not much more than that. Can someone walk me through this problem? What are the concepts that I should be seeing?

(btw, I think the problem may be awkwardly worded - it's the professor's)

Answer (score 1):

$P(70)=P($living 5 more years$) \cap P(65)=(1-.16)(.746)=.62664.$

EDIT: Since we know that the probability that the man will live $5$ more years if he is $65$ is $1-.16=.84$. This is equivalent to saying:

$P(70|65)=.84$

Recall that $P(A|B)=\frac{P(A\cap B)}{P(B)}$. So $P(70|65)=\frac{P(70\cap(65)}{P(65)}=\frac{P(70)}{P(65)}$

$\therefore P(70)=P(65)P(70|65)$, yielding the above result.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, Mathster. I have several questions for you.

1) I thought that the union of two events can be expressed as the their sum. As I try to find my notes on set theory, can you please explain why its, instead, their product?

2) Why doesn't the union also include P(55) and P(50)?


3) My professor gave us this problem to test our knowledge on conditional probability. Do you see how this problem can be done using conditional probability?

Comment: @CormanoSanchez Sorry, I meant made a typo and edited it to intersection. I'll edit in a way to do it using conditional probability.

Comment: I see, you've edited your comment - you've used the intersection symbol. I retract my first question, then! Maybe you can answer the others, though? EDIT: Thanks!

Comment: @CarmanoSanchez Done!

Comment: Sorry, another question: doesn't P(65)P(70|65) yield P(70 ∩ 65), not P(70)?EDIT: Just saw your latest edit, might obviate my question... lemme take a look. :D

Comment: Ok, how does P(70 ∩ 65) simplify to P(70)? I think this is the key to my understanding the problem!

Comment: But $P(70)=P(70 \cap 60)$, as I showed above! Turning $70$ is a subspace of the event of turning $65$, since he must first turn $65$ to turn $70$. By this same reasoning, we can ignore the events of turning $50$ and $55$ because turning $65$ is a subspace of both of those; that is, $P(65)=P(65 \cap 55)$ and $P(65)=P(65 \cap 50)$. **In Layman's terms, one must first reach $65$ to reach $70$, so the intersection of both of those events is simply the event of turning $70$!**

Comment: Oh, of course! You are right, of course! Was not being very careful, there. Thanks so much for your help! What a wonderful website!

Comment: Glad to help! And sorry I wasn't very clear the first time. I agree - this is a wonderful website!

Answer (score 0):

In general when you're given the probabilities of several related events, and then asked to compute the probability of some other related event, you should try to partition or express the new event in terms of the previously mentioned ones.

For example, if one would like the probability of a given person getting married in the next year, and one knows the probability of a male getting married in the next year, and the probability of a female getting married in the next year, one has partitioned the event "a person getting married in the next year" into two mutually exclusive ones. This allows you to add probabilities.

In this case it's even easier. You should try to think to yourself what MUST be true if a man survives until his 70th birthday.....

Hint: He has to survive until his 65th, and then additionally live at least a certain number of years....

Comment: Thanks for your reply, BlueBuck. Your explanation is very helpful, and your hint pretty much gives away the conditions that must obtain for a man to survive to age 70. A question, though: isn't also true that, to reach 65, a man must first reach 55, and so on? How do I know when to stop the nested conditions?